| . + in jq meaning
I'm not sure what the dot and plus sign after a pipe mean, and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about this. For example, when looking up a title in a Json object, I would write
| . + {Title: $departments[.Code].Title}
what is happening in this line of code?

Are you sure that's not part of a JQ command? The pipe is the only bash syntax here...

Actually I think it is. What does this command do in JQ?

It returns a string concatenation. Can you please show the json?

In jq, the dot is the identity function. It reproduces what the part before the pipe evaluated to. Then, + adds to it a constructed object with a Title field, merging both into a single combined object. Another way of writing this would be using plain assignment: | .Title = $departments[.Code].Title

in bash | . + is not valid, but cmd | . +  attempts to source a file named + and passes the output of cmd so it can be used by a command in +. Consider date | . <(echo nl) or seq 3 | . <(echo 'read a; read b; read c; echo "$a/$b/$c"')

and {Title: $department[.Code].Title} will be treated as two (or more, depending on the expansion of $department) arguments to the sourced file. run help . inside bash

In the future, avoid downvotes by including a [mcve] (I didn't downvote). Good luck.

I find the claim "I found nothing on the internet" absurd, given . is the very first of the basic filters in the documentation. (and | comes in at number 10 of the basic filters).

What you have there is not correct on its own. It's part of something larger
... | . + {Title: $departments[.Code].Title}

The code represented by ... produces a stream of values.
. + {Title: $departments[.Code].Title} is evaluated for each of those values.
. is the value for which the expression is being evaluated.
For example, let's say the code represented by ... produces the following objects:

{ "Code": "ANI", ... }
{ "Code": "HR", ... }

. + {Title: $departments[.Code].Title} will be evaluated twice.
The first time . + {Title: $departments[.Code].Title} is evaluated, . will be { "Code": "ANI", ... }, and it will produce something like { "Code": "ANI", ..., "Title": "Animation" }.
The second time . + {Title: $departments[.Code].Title} is evaluated, . will be { "Code": "HR", ... }, and it will produce something like { "Code": "HR", ..., "Title": "Human Resources" }.
It could also have been written as
... | .Title = $departments[.Code].Title

